# container with low pressure inside of the high pressure container

Tags: pressure

How will act low pressure container, or what would happen inside the low pressure container when it is placed inside the container with high pressure?

And if it is high pressure container inside the high pressure container?
Will the container which is inside stay in the centre?

Comment: Why do you think it should stay in the center?

Comment: ok, no matter what I will say you already mark this as wrong

Comment: probably because placing equal high pressure on high pressure would give a total of 1 or 0, that means the object would stay on its place, as there would be a magnetic field and we are on earth(atom would stay in the centre), the object will stay in the centre.

Answer (score 1):

If your inner container is a solid box (i.e. rigid walls), then nothing will happen.

If the inner container is a balloon (interesting case), then it will shrink until the pressure of the balloon is equal to the pressure of the outer container plus an extra pressure necessary to stretch the balloon to the respective volume.

About the position of the inner container: it will fall as everything, except in the case that the buoyancy is stronger than the weight of the container:
$$F_{buoyancy}=V(\rho_{out}-\rho_{in})g>m_{container}g=F_{weight}$$

in the case this condition is fulfilled, the inner container will go up.
In the case you have an equality between the two forces, then it will float.

Comment: great suggestion about the balloon, actually I was thinking about the pressure that affects human.
OK, you sort of explained it. What about the same idea, but in vacuum.
How about, in case with rigid walls and very high pressure inside the outer container, will the high pressure squeeze out or destroy the inner container?

Comment: The difference between rigid walls and expandable (like a balloon) is relative, since rigid materials can also expand under relatively high stress.

On the other hand, it's ok to think about vacuum, but you could also think about going under water, at great depth; beyond a certain depth, the water pressure will hurt you, and probably injure you severely, by what is called barotrauma.